# Mail Script not working

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I am stuck and cannot figure out for the life of me why this is not working. It was working before. I have changed the emails addresses below for security reasons.

```
$to = "email@domainname.com";
$subject = "Submission";
$body = "Test Body";
$header = "From: email@domainname.com";                
if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $header)) {
    echo "message was successfully sent.";
    echo "$to $subject <br/> $body <br/> $header";
} else {
    echo "There was a Problem.";
};
```

Comment: Define "not working". Does it show "There was a Problem" or does it say it sent but doesn't?

Comment: There are no errors and says it sent even in the logs. I have checked by mail server and there have been no emails received by the mail server or any caught in spam.

Comment: remove the header and see what happens: mail($to, $subject, $body)

Comment: It was working before what? What changed?

Comment: I removed the header and still says message sent. Nothing changed that is what is weird. I am the only person with access to anything and it just stopped working.

Comment: Have you Checked check if mailserver is running: `nmap <server ip> -p 25 |grep open` ?

Comment: just checked and mailserver is indeed running.

Comment: Check this page, it covers the same issue! [Stackoverflow :: PHP mail() doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6403746/352449)

Comment: Have you tried sending mail to multiple, unrelated addresses/domains?

Comment: @Zuul I am checking that page now and j08691 I have tried my work, personal(live.com), a gmail and other email accounts does not change anything.

Comment: @Zuul i have gone over everything in that post and everything is correct or i just tried it.

Comment: Do you know for sure that the destination account is receiving mails?

Comment: Yes, I have been actively receiving emails all day from my customers.

Comment: if you're trying this on *nix server, what if you run this: "tcpdump -nvvXS port 25" from root? Do you see somewhere in packet contents 250.Accepted or something like that? What do you see in packet contents before QUIT command

Comment: I looked at our mail server and changed the spam filter settings just to see what would happen. Low and behold everything is working fine now. The odd thing is it wasn't showing that the email had even been received. But regardless problem solved. Thanks everyone for their help it is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at our mail server and changed the spam filter settings just to see what would happen. Low and behold everything is working fine now. The odd thing is it wasn't showing that the email had even been received. But regardless problem solved. Thanks everyone for their help it is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**First**: You have to be sure that your ambiente is configured properly. Your script will not show error messages either.

**Hint**: User **PHPMailer**. (http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)
This class show spefic messages, and them you can fix whats is wrong.

**Important**:
If you are unsure where is the error, you will be frustrated in trying and trying without directions. There can be many causes for the e-mail will not be sent.

Use PHPMail and find out where is the bug, after that you can ask here again, the advantage is that you have a description of the error.

I had a similar problem and PHPMail helped me a lot!

So, try it and tell us the error.