# Sending form data to E-mail with PHP

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to send form data to my E-mail with no success. I want that when the user click on "submit" button (and after validation) the data field will send to my e-mail and the user see a message "Thank you for contacting us" instead of the form field. I am very new with PHP and hope one of you can help me.

This is my HTML form:

```
    <form id="contactForm" method="post" action="contact.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Full Name">

            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail Address">

            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">

            <input type="text" name="company" id="company" placeholder="Company">

            <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Write Your Message Here..."></textarea>

            <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="submitForm">
</form>
```

and this is my PHP Code:

```
<?php

if($_POST["submit"]) {
    $recipient="myEmail@gmail.com";
    $subject="Message from Website";
    $sender=$_POST["name"];
    $senderEmail=$_POST["email"];
    $senderPhone=$_POST["phone"];
    $senderCompany=$_POST["company"];
    $message=$_POST["message"];

    $mailBody="Name: $sender\nEmail: $senderEmail\nPhone: $senderPhone\nCompany: $senderCompany\n\n$message";

    mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$senderEmail>");

$thankYou="<p>Thank you! Your message has been sent.</p>";
}

?>
```

I also have JS validation function to this form called validateForm() which works fine. Should I need to define something on the hosting server to make this PHP works?

Comment: Did you check error log? If there is any error, please share it. And system details, and which OS, which webserver(apache, ..) etc too

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403746/php-mail-doesnt-work) you can find a lot of possible solutions.

Comment: PLease set headers for the mail funciton. PLease refer to PHP manual. You will get your trick

Comment: What output do you get when you submit the form? Some error or what?

Comment: I did not get any errors. When I submit the form, I just moved to a blank contact.php page.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines to the top of your script

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", "On");
```

If your server is not configured correctly with mail you will see errors. 
The best practice is to use PHPMailer. With that you can use sendmail or any SMTP server

Comment: Thanks, now I get this error:

Notice: Undefined index: submit in /home/mywebsite/public_html/contact.php on line 7

line 7 is:
if($_POST["submit"]) {

Comment: if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']){

but that is unrelated to your mailing problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using something like PHPMailer?

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/

Its a class that'll send the email with the appropriate headers and is both easy to use and debug.

You'll also find that since it has the appropriate headers, spam filters wont stop it from reaching the correct destination.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<input type="submit" value="SEND" id="submit">
```

UPDATE:

It is the `name="xx"` attribute of the input button that is used to give a variable name to the values passed on the $_POST or $_GET arrays

So you need to add a `name="submit"` to the button html tag like so

```
<input type="submit" value="SEND" name="submit">
```

Now this PHP statement will work as it will see a named variable called 'submit' in the $_POST array

```
if ( $_POST['submit'] )
```

Comment: Please try to explain why your answer will resolve the OP problems, reading it as is let newcomers/beginners wondering why id should be submit and not something else ?