# Contact Form fails to send out an email

Tags: php, email, contact-form

After filling up the contact form with valid information, and hitting submit, I get a message of success! But, on checking the my inbox, I don't the email. 
What is wrong ?

P.S. I have checked my web server. It sends out mail but this contact forms just fails.

`Contact Form`

```
<section class="span8 ">
    <div class="col-right">
        <hr>
        <h4>General Enquire or Apply</h4>

        <div id="message-contact"></div>
        <form method="post" action="assets/contact.php" id="contactform">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span3">
                    <label>Name <span class="required">* </span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="span3 ie7-margin" id="name_contact">
                </div>
                <div class="span3">
                    <label>Last name <span class="required">* </span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="span3 ie7-margin" id="lastname_contact">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span3">
                    <label>Email <span class="required">* </span></label>
                    <input type="email" id="email_contact" class="span3 ie7-margin">
                </div>
                <div class="span3">
                    <label>Phone <span class="required">* </span></label>
                    <input type="text" id="phone_contact" class="span3 ie7-margin">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span3">
                    <label>Select a department</label>
                    <select id="subject_contact" class="span3">
                        <option value="Administration">Administration</option>
                        <option value="Admissions">Admissions</option>
                        <option value="Courses">Courses</option>
                        <option value="Apply">Apply</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span3">
                    <label>Message <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <textarea rows="5" id="message_contact" class="span6"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span3">
                    <label><span class="required">*</span> Are you human? 3 + 1 =</label>
                    <input type="text" id="verify_contact" class="span2">
                </div>
                <div class="button-align span3">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit-contact" value="Submit" class=" button_medium">
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </form>

        <h4>Plan a visit</h4>
        <div id="message-visit"></div>
        <form method="post" action="assets/visit.php" id="visit">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span3">
                    <label>Name <span class="required">* </span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="span3 ie7-margin" id="name_visit">
                </div>
                <div class="span3">
                    <label>Last name <span class="required">* </span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="span3 ie7-margin" id="lastname_visit">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span3">
                    <label>Email <span class="required">* </span></label>
                    <input type="email" id="email_visit" class="span3 ie7-margin">
                </div>
                <div class="span3">
                    <label>Phone <span class="required">* </span></label>
                    <input type="text" id="phone_visit" class="span3 ie7-margin">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span3">
                    <div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append">
                        <label>Select a date <span class="required">* </span></label>
                        <input type="text" class=" dateinput" id="date_visit" readonly>
                        <span class="add-on"><i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span3">
                    <label><span class="required">*</span> Are you human? 3 + 1 =</label>
                    <input type="text" id="verify_visit" class="span2">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end row-->
            <input type="submit" id="submit-visit" value="Submit" class=" button_medium">
        </form>

    </div><!-- end col right-->
    </section>
```

`contact.php`

```
<?php

if(!$_POST) exit;

// Email verification, do not edit.
function isEmail($email_contact ) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email_contact ));
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$name_contact     = $_POST['name_contact'];
$lastname_contact    = $_POST['lastname_contact'];
$email_contact    = $_POST['email_contact'];
$phone_contact   = $_POST['phone_contact'];
$subject_contact  = $_POST['subject_contact'];
$message_contact = $_POST['message_contact'];
$verify_contact   = $_POST['verify_contact'];

if(trim($name_contact) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message"><i class=" icon-warning-sign"></i> You must enter your Name.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($lastname_contact ) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message"><i class=" icon-warning-sign"></i>You must enter your Last name.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($email_contact) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message"><i class=" icon-warning-sign"></i>Please enter a valid email address.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email_contact)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message"><i class=" icon-warning-sign"></i> You have enter an invalid e-mail address, try again.</div>';
    exit();
    } else if(trim($phone_contact) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Please enter a valid phone number.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!is_numeric($phone_contact)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Phone number can only contain numbers.</div>';
    exit();
}
if(trim($subject_contact) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message"><i class=" icon-warning-sign"></i> Please select a department.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($message_contact) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message"><i class=" icon-warning-sign"></i> Please enter your message.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isset($verify_contact) || trim($verify_contact) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message"><i class=" icon-warning-sign"></i> Please enter the verification number.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($verify_contact) != '4') {
    echo '<div class="error_message"><i class=" icon-warning-sign"></i> The verification number you entered is incorrect.</div>';
    exit();
}

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $message_contact = stripslashes($message_contact);
}


//$address = "HERE your email address";
$address = "staff@domain.com";


// Below the subject of the email
$e_subject = 'You\'ve been contacted by ' . $name_contact . '.';

// You can change this if you feel that you need to.
$e_body = "You have been contacted by $name_contact $lastname_contact with attention to $subject_contact, with additional message is as follows." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = "\"$message_contact\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "You can contact $lastname_contact via email, $email_contact or via phone $phone_contact";

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: $email_contact" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_contact" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

    // Success message
    echo "<div id='success_page' style='padding:20px'>";
    echo "<strong >Email Sent.</strong>";
    echo "Thank you <strong>$name_contact</strong>,<br> your message has been submitted. We will contact you shortly.";
    echo "</div>";

} else {

    echo 'ERROR!';

}
?>
```

Comment: is mail() works? test with direct input. if works then check the values you are passing.

Comment: are you trying to send the mail server, if yes then you localhost should forward that mail to your public ip which has port 25 open

Comment: [with mail(), 'success' means nothing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403746/php-mail-doesnt-work)

Comment: @PraveenD - `mail()` is working!

Comment: Ok, Update your form as per below answer and check all values are coming in print_r($_POST).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add name attribute with each controller.

Example

```
<input type="text" class="span3 ie7-margin" id="name_contact">
```

Replace with

```
<input type="text" class="span3 ie7-margin" name="name_contact" id="name_contact">
```

[name="name_contact"] added

=====

If you get success message but mail not sent then check mail server logs at
C:\xampp\apache\mailoutput

If mail() returns true, thus php job is done. there is server side issue.

Comment: Does not seem to work :(

Comment: Its working here for me mail function returns true.  May be mail quota expired. Contact with hosting provider. Email Sent.Thank you Praveen,
your message has been submitted. We will contact you shortly.

Comment: Did you try with my code snippet ?

Comment: I updated controls with name attribute.

Comment: yes, no change in contact.php

Comment: Okay. Kindly check this for errors - http://pastebin.com/qSTipgNn and notify!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80266/discussion-between-maven-maverick-and-praveend).

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the input name with the "name" argument, not the with the id. So replace "id" with "name".

Replace this

```
<form method="post" action="assets/contact.php" id="contactform">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span3">
                    <label>Name <span class="required">* </span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="span3 ie7-margin" id="name_contact">
                </div>
                <div class="span3">
                    <label>Last name <span class="required">* </span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="span3 ie7-margin" id="lastname_contact">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span3">
                    <label>Email <span class="required">* </span></label>
                    <input type="email" id="email_contact" class="span3 ie7-margin">
                </div>
                <div class="span3">
                    <label>Phone <span class="required">* </span></label>
                    <input type="text" id="phone_contact" class="span3 ie7-margin">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span3">
                    <label>Select a department</label>
                    <select id="subject_contact" class="span3">
                        <option value="Administration">Administration</option>
                        <option value="Admissions">Admissions</option>
                        <option value="Courses">Courses</option>
                        <option value="Apply">Apply</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span3">
                    <label>Message <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <textarea rows="5" id="message_contact" class="span6"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span3">
                    <label><span class="required">*</span> Are you human? 3 + 1 =</label>
                    <input type="text" id="verify_contact" class="span2">
                </div>
                <div class="button-align span3">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit-contact" value="Submit" class=" button_medium">
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </form>
```

with

```
<form method="post" action="assets/contact.php" id="contactform">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span3">
                    <label>Name <span class="required">* </span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="span3 ie7-margin" name="name_contact"><!-- Replaced id with name -->
                </div>
                <div class="span3">
                    <label>Last name <span class="required">* </span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="span3 ie7-margin" name="lastname_contact"><!-- Replaced id with name -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span3">
                    <label>Email <span class="required">* </span></label>
                    <input type="email" name="email_contact" class="span3 ie7-margin"><!-- Replaced id with name -->
                </div>
                <div class="span3">
                    <label>Phone <span class="required">* </span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="phone_contact" class="span3 ie7-margin"><!-- Replaced id with name -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span3">
                    <label>Select a department</label>
                    <select name="subject_contact" class="span3"><!-- Replaced id with name -->
                        <option value="Administration">Administration</option>
                        <option value="Admissions">Admissions</option>
                        <option value="Courses">Courses</option>
                        <option value="Apply">Apply</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span3">
                    <label>Message <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <textarea rows="5" name="message_contact" class="span6"></textarea><!-- Replaced id with name -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span3">
                    <label><span class="required">*</span> Are you human? 3 + 1 =</label>
                    <input type="text" name="verify_contact" class="span2"><!-- Replaced id with name -->
                </div>
                <div class="button-align span3">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit-contact" value="Submit" class=" button_medium"><!-- Replaced id with name -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </form>
```

and regarding the way to send emails in php, check out this very detailed answer here: [PHP mail form doesn't complete sending e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-form-doesnt-complete-sending-e-mail)

Comment: Please place comment for your changes.

Comment: It is not working :(